Getting request with auth token via Angular Interceptor and Intercepting further calls
I'm trying to authenticate to an API first and then "attach" the token to each one of my requests, but the one including 'connect'.
I have the following:
Interceptor
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!request.url.includes('/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials')) {
      this.authService.isTokenExist()
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          return error;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((token: any) => {
        if (token) {
          request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request); // here I'm hitting the point without token and I think this is the problem
  }
}


Service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaderResponse,
  HttpHeaders,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environment';
import { urlString } from '../../utils/helpers';
import { Observable, catchError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getToken(): Observable<string | null> {
    const requestBody: Request = {
      client_id: environment.client_id,
      client_secret: environment.client_secret,
      grant_type: environment.grant_type,
      scope: environment.scope,
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    const options = { headers };
    return this.http
      .post<Response>(
        `${environment.api_url}/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials`,
        urlString(requestBody),
        options
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          throw error;
        }),
        map((response: Response) => {
          this.setToken(response.access_token);
          return response.access_token;
        })
      );
  }

  getFileMetadata(fileId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
      `${environment.api_url}/api/v1.4/items/${fileId}/_metadata`
    );
  }

  isTokenExist(): Observable<string | null> {
    const tokenTime = localStorage.getItem('token_time');
    if (tokenTime) {
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const tokenTimeInt = parseInt(tokenTime, 10);
      if (currentTime - tokenTimeInt > 86400000) {
        return this.getToken();
      }
    } else {
      this.getToken().subscribe({
        next: (token) => {
          if (token) {
            this.setToken(token);
          }
          return of(token);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          throw error;
        }
      });
    }
    return of(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  }

  setToken(token: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('token_', token);
    localStorage.setItem('token_time', new Date().getTime().toString());
  }
}

interface Request {
  grant_type: string;
  client_secret: string;
  client_id: string;
  scope: string;
}

interface Response {
  access_token: string;
  token_type: string;
  expires_in: number;
}

The result is that on the first-page load, I get 401, as the interceptor is just passing the request. The service returns the token on refresh, and the request passes as expected.
My question is, how can we hold the Interceptor until the token is available and then intercept all other calls?

Maybe you can use async / await?

I've got a bit rusty with the latest Angular, but yes, you are right; it could be async imperative flavor. But I've read on the web that angular direction is more reactive. That's why I'm trying to follow it with RxJs.

I see, well I'm more experienced in Vue, but with vue-router you can conditionally user a middleware / interceptor to check if you need auth / token, maybe this is the way to go?

I did this refactoring in the interceptor:
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.includes('/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials')) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    return this.authService.isTokenExist().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        throw error;
      }),
      switchMap((token: string) => {
        const headers = request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        const newRequest = request.clone({ headers });
        return next.handle(newRequest);
      })
    );
  }
}

...and in service, I changed methods like this:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaderResponse,
  HttpHeaders,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environment';
import { urlString } from '../../utils/helpers';
import { Observable, catchError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getToken(): Observable<string> {
    const requestBody: Request = {
      client_id: environment.client_id,
      client_secret: environment.client_secret,
      grant_type: environment.grant_type,
      scope: environment.scope,
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    const options = { headers };
    return this.http
      .post<Response>(
        `${environment.api_url}/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials`,
        urlString(requestBody),
        options
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          throw error;
        }),
        map((response: Response) => {
          this.setToken(response.access_token);
          return response.access_token;
        })
      );
  }

  isTokenExist(): Observable<any> {
    const tokenTime = localStorage.getItem('token_time');
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (tokenTime) {
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const tokenTimeInt = parseInt(tokenTime, 10);
      if (currentTime - tokenTimeInt > 86400000) {
        return this.getToken();
      }
    }

    if (!token) {
      return this.getToken();
    }

    return of(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  }

  setToken(token: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('token_time', new Date().getTime().toString());
  }

  getFileMetadata(fileId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
      `${environment.api_url}/api/v1.4/items/${fileId}/_metadata`
    );
  }

  getFileBlob(uniformName: string, path: string): Observable<Blob> {
    const currentPath = path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    return this.http.get(
      `${environment.api_url}/content/v1.4/${currentPath}/${uniformName}/_blob`,
      { responseType: 'blob' }
    );
  }
}

interface Request {
  grant_type: string;
  client_secret: string;
  client_id: string;
  scope: string;
}

interface Response {
  access_token: string;
  token_type: string;
  expires_in: number;
}

Basically the refactoring is in the Interceptor intercept function:
...
if (request.url.includes('/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials')) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    return this.authService.isTokenExist().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        throw error;
      }),
      switchMap((token: string) => {
        const headers = request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        const newRequest = request.clone({ headers });
        return next.handle(newRequest);
      })
    );
....

Where by using early return is the request isn't a one for token.
There service further, I'm returning an Observable instead if a string or null and a bit more logic in the method `isTokeExist()'

Could you please refer the content your're explaining, please? It improves it's integrity, please?

yeah, sure - I'll edit it.

One advice would be to take the token from local storage since your already set it there. Most probably you save it on login and should be available for every call you will do afterwards. You should not call an endpoint in interceptor. Interceptors are primarily designed to inspect and manipulate HTTP requests and responses globally, such as adding headers, logging, or handling errors.
Then in interceptor you can get your token and attach it to header
const token = localStorage.getItem(‘token’);
let headers = request.headers;
if (token) {
 headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
}
 const req = request.clone({ headers });

And then pass the new ‘req’ as your request.

Please answer with facts, not "advices". It's cool to add something but always try to direct answer the question and link some sources, please? :)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Andrei I see your point here
